# update_user_meta(): invisible data storage

Tags: custom-field, database, user-meta, profiles

I try to customize users profile using this code (from [this](http://b-website.com/ajouter-des-information-aux-profils-utilisateur-dans-wordpress) tutorial) :

```
<?php function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

  <h3>Autres</h3>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Entreprise</th>
        <td><input class="regular-text" id="entreprise" type="text" name="entreprise" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'entreprise', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>OS</th>
        <td><input class="regular-text" id="os" type="text" name="os" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'os', $user->ID ) ); ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<?php }
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'entreprise', $_POST['entreprise'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'os', $_POST['os'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' ); ?>
```

I saw a strange thing when I tried to add custom user meta data into Wordpress; I save custom data on a user's profile, the data is saved on the page and I can see it even if I reload it, but when I take a look in the database, the table _usermeta hasn't changed at all; the custom data is nowhere ! I tried other tutorials, there isn't any php problem, but it doesn't change.

It's driving me mad, where are the data stored then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be stored in the `wp_usermeta` table under the `entreprise` and `os` user meta keys.

You should consider using *prefix* on your custom meta keys, to avoid name collison. Example:

```
kerzzy_entreprise 
kerzzy_os
```

It should show up with:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'entreprise'
```

in your MySQL administration tool, e.g. *PHPMyAdmin*.

... and make sure you're in the correct database ;-)

Comment: I made a request into phpMyAdmin then I saw them. The next lines (after ~30) into the main request were only hidden, that's why I didn't saw them (yeah phpMyAdmin). One reason why command line is better.. I was searching too far for this silly tiny detail. Thank you to have opened my blind eyes and for your quick answer ^^

Comment: glad to hear it worked out for you @Kerzzy